# How print field of another node

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, field

I know, that I can print a field from current node in template by e.g.

```
<?php print render($field['title_field']); ?>
```

but how I can print another nodes field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get that node id somehow, then load whole node:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
```

Inside that $node object you'll have your field value. print_r or var_dump $node to see exact structure and how to approach your field value.

Comment: thanks for showing me a good way to done this ;)
If anyone needs more in future reading this, I'm pasting whole code below:
<code>
    $nid = 813;
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $title = field_get_items('node', $node, 'title_field');
    print $title[0]['value'];
    $body = field_get_items('node', $node, 'body');
    print $body[0]['value'];
</code>

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 with the help of entity concept you can print any field.

```
field_view_value($entity_type, $entity, $field_name, $item, $display = array(), $langcode = NULL)
```

Ref : https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7